# Restricting ssh access for local user with exception

Tags: linux, ssh, aix

I have a local user in AIX system now my management want to restrict ssh access for that local user except two servers.

I tried many options in ssh configuration by creating AllowUsers, DenyUsers, Match(conditional block) but nothing works. I can deny access for that user throughout but wondering where to give exception for those two servers.

Inn sshd config

DenyUsers user1

Match Address "ip of the system i need access"

```
  AllowUsers user1
```

They way i mentioned above is right? Please advise.

Also let me know if there is any other approach for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: sshd config applies only to the server it is on. so you will need different configuration content on the server where this user has access and where he has not. As written in the documentation, by default access is granted, so you might instead need `DenyUsers` on the servers where he should not connect. At some point you may wish to define groups of users and/or manage centrally all servers SSH configuration (puppet, chef, ansible, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for you response!!! i believe i was not clear with my issue earlier. I have a local user id "user1" in one server for where i need to disable ssh access from all servers except two systems. Adding DenyUser user1 will block ssh access for the user wondering where to give for those two servers. Trying using conditional block "match" in sshd configuration but it is not working

Comment: Indeed I still fail to grasp exactly the question. You may wish to edit your post, and add examples, like: serverA, serverB, serverC and something like "I want user1 on serverA to be able to connect to serverB but not to serverC" or something like that. Currently, I do not understand your setup, which servers you have, where are your users, *from* where *to* where are your connections, which should be allowed and which should be refused.

Comment: Why can you not configure most of the servers to Deny user1? Leave the two other servers *without* the "DenyUser user1", and that user could ssh in to them...?

Comment: Thanks all for your response!! i was able to figure out a solution using match and restricting passwd auth for that user instead using private key.